# .NET HttpWebRequest only works if a HTTPS sniffer is on

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, varnish, tls1.2

im trying to send a simple GET request to a varnish server and the code below only works if a http sniffer is ON, otherwise im getting a 430 
Unauthorized response, if you visit this url https://identity.ticketmaster.com/v1/me you should get 400 status code cause no credential is specified but instead with the code below, we get 430 Unauthorized

```
userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36";
Uri requestUri = new Uri("https://identity.ticketmaster.com/v1/me");
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Host = "identity.ticketmaster.com";
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
request.UserAgent = userAgent;
request.Accept = "*/*";
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
string str = "";
try{
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
str = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(str);
response.Close();
request.Abort();
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

with any browser it works ok also if i build the request with any other request builder it works. Looks like somehow varnish is able to detect if the request is being sent by a .NET app and fire the 430 Unauthorized message.
I tried wireshark and the only difference i can see is the TLS1.2 handshake

Comment: Your browser may be sending cookies if you've already authenticated.  When I try just the Uri you show I get a 400 response. `{"errorId":"","message":"","description":"","errors":[{"status":400,"title":"Missing credentials"},{"title":"Missing credentials","detail":"Required at least one method of authentication, none provided"}]}`

Comment: 400 is the normal response we should get on browser if no authentication/cookies is sent but if you try the above code you will get a 430 (Unauthorized ) response.

Comment: what about `with any browser it works ok` in your post?

Comment: i mean with any browser we get the 400 response witch is ok because no credential/cookie is specified, but with the code above we get 430, we should get the 400 response both on any browser and with the code above

Comment: ya got me.  Hope you post your answer cuz now I'm curious